# Why does this code need the tcolorbox package?

Tags: tcolorbox, foreach, includegraphics

Why does this code need the tcolorbox package to compile?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\def\Image{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image.jpg}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}{
\Image
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well you need pgffor for the  \foreach, and graphicx for the graphic. Side remark: don't use only \def, you don't know if you redefine an important command with it. Use \newcommand, either instead or before the \def.

Answer (score 2):

As Ulrike Fischer told, what you need is `pgffor` and `graphicx` packages. This is the minimal code.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\Image{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image.jpg}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}{
\Image
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

But `tcolorbox` loads `pgf` package which loads `graphicx` and `pgffor` and allows to compile your code. If you want to work with `tcolorbox` your code is correct, but it will load too much code for your example.